# Python pandas: summing value of two or more DataFrames with identical value in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["tom", 1, 2, 3], ["bob", 3, 4, 5], ["ali", 6, 7, 8]], columns=["name", "A", "B", "C"])
df1
Out[44]: 
  name  A  B  C
0  tom  1  2  3
1  bob  3  4  5
2  ali  6  7  8
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["rob", 1, 2, 3], ["ali", 6, 7, 8]], columns=["name", "A", "B", "D"])
df2
Out[46]: 
  name  A  B  D
0  rob  1  2  3
1  ali  6  7  8
```

how can I perform a sum operations to the values with same 'name' and same column, and get a result DataFrame like:

```
  name A   B   C   D
0  tom 1   2   3 NaN     # <- tom and bob don't shows up in df2, so the sum is identical
1  bob 3   4   5 NaN     #    to their values in df1
2  rob 1   2 NaN   3     # <- rob only shows up on df2, so the sum equal to its df2 values
3  ali 12 14   8   8     # <- ali's A and B are sum up, and C and D are identical to their
                         #    corresponding value in df1 and df2
```

please note, I don't know what names will show up in 'name' columns of both DataFrames.

And, because I have more than two such DataFrames to sum up, how can I do this with all of them in one operation, instead of sum up one by one, if that is possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your problem. I have modified Nan as 0.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["tom", 1, 2, 3], ["bob", 3, 4, 5], ["ali", 6, 7, 8]], columns=["name", "A", "B", "C"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["rob", 1, 2, 3], ["ali", 6, 7, 8]], columns=["name", "A", "B", "D"])
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df4=df3.groupby(['name'])['A','B','C','D'].sum()
print(df4)
```

Answer (score 1):

**(1) If your df1 and df2 does not contain duplicate names within one dataframe (still can have duplicates across 2 dataframes):**

You can use [`.add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0` after we [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to column `name` on the 2 dataframes, as follows:

```
df3 = (df1.set_index('name')
          .add(df2.set_index('name'), fill_value=0)
      ).reset_index()
```

**`NaN` values for non-matching entries are retained in this way.**

By setting index to the same `name` column, Pandas knows to align rows with the same row index (same name) before the add operation.  Hence, we can get the correct sum with same name.

Result:

```
print(df3)

  name     A     B    C    D
0  ali  12.0  14.0  8.0  8.0
1  bob   3.0   4.0  5.0  NaN
2  rob   1.0   2.0  NaN  3.0
3  tom   1.0   2.0  3.0  NaN
```

**(2) If your df1 and df2 contain duplicate names within one dataframe:**

If your df1 and df2 contain duplicate names in within one dataframe, you can use:

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
         .groupby('name', as_index=False)
         .sum()
      )
```

Result:

```
print(df3)

  name   A   B     C    D
0  ali  12  14   8.0  8.0
1  bob   3   4   5.0  0.0
2  rob   1   2   0.0  3.0
3  tom  12  14  16.0  0.0
```

In this way, the `NaN` values of non-matching entries are padded with `0`.